# nginx disable directory browsing not working

Tags: nginx, security, django

I have a Django application in production and my web server is Nginx.

My application is located at `/home/rouizi/blog` and let say my domain name is `example.com`.
I want to prevent that users can read my files that are located inside the `blog` folder.

For instance, with my actual configuration, if someone access `exemple.com/manage.py` he can see the content of that file. I want instead to show him a `404 not found` error.

Here is my nginx configuration:

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;

pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

       add_header    X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
       add_header    X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
       add_header    X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

       server_tokens off;
       keepalive_timeout 75;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf**

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen         80;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com;
    return         301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                          443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen                          [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    
    #  ssl stuff

    server_name                     example.com www.example.com;
    root                            /home/rouizi/blog/;
    index                           index.html;

    location /static {
        alias /home/rouizi/blog/staticfiles/;
     }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }
    }

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  3;
    gzip_types       text/plain text/css application/javascript image/*;
}
```

What I tried so far:

I added the directive `autoindex  on;` and reload nginx. Not worked

I added an empty `index.html` file inside the `blog directory` and reload nginx. Not worked

How can I solve this problem ?

**Edit**

I found that If I put my ip address instead of my domain name in the `server_name` directive the directory browsing is disabled:

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf**

```
# ...

server {
    # ...
    #  ssl stuff

    server_name                     139.151.187.143;
    
    # ...

}
```

Just like that if I go to `exemple.com/manage.py` or other files I get a `404 not found` error from my Dango application. But also static and media files are no longer served.

Anyone can explain why ? Is this reloated to my DNS hosting provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serving anything other than the files specifically copied to a `static` folder is not typically what you want for Django-powered applications.

The [typical setup](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) works like this:

1. everything in `/static` gets handled by the web server
   (this is what the `location /static {}` block is about: the `alias` points to the directory where the django `collectstatic` commands places static files)
2. similar handling of a `/media` location, as necessary
3. everything else gets forwarded to the wsgi application
   (meaning your program files are *not* directly accessed by the *nginx* server)

What you want it probably remove the `root /home/rouizi/blog/;` and unconditionally (not inside a `if (!-f $request_filename) {` block) forward requests to your wsgi application.

Comment: if I remove the condition `if (!-f $request_filename)` static and media files are no longer server by the web server. all requests are forwarded to the Django app. and Django don't handle static and media files.

Comment: You are right! actually, if I remove the condition `if (!-f $request_filename)` only media files are no longer served by the web server Nginx because I didn't add the location for media files. So what I did is: remove the condition `if (!-f $request_filename)` and add the directive `location /media  {alias /var/www/blog/media/;}`. Thank you man, I was stuck for days!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the application that is running at `127.0.0.1:8000` to block these requests.

nginx simply passes all requests starting with `/` to your web application, except for requests starting with `/static`.

Comment: Any idea of how can I block requests with my Django app ? But why in local development if I try to navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000/manage.py` I get a `404 not found` error from my django app. Why this is not the same in production?

Comment: @YacineRouiz Your Python files should not be in the document `root` at all. They should be elsewhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Where should I put them? I tried to put my project in `/var/www/blog` but I still can see the content of the files